# Browser not rendering Dockerized AngularJS app

Tags: node.js, angularjs, docker, npm

So, I'm trying to dockerize an AngularJS app for some practice. Here is my repo https://github.com/Nigel33/angularJS_docker_test: 
(Its from the official Angular-phonecat repo but i added Dockerfile and docker-compose)

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine
RUN npm install -g http-server

WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./

COPY . .

RUN npm install && \
    npm run start

EXPOSE 8000

CMD [ "http-server", "dist" ]
```

Here's my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  front:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "npm start"
    volumes: 
      - .:/angular-phonecat
    ports: 
      - "8000:8000"
```

When I do docker-compose build then docker-compose up, it seems to run based on the logs:

```
Building front
Step 1/8 : FROM node:lts-alpine
 ---> b95baba1cfdb
Step 2/8 : RUN npm install -g http-server
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 082793f64510
Step 3/8 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e76e23fa5a08
Step 4/8 : COPY package*.json ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9960651e0929
Step 5/8 : COPY . .
 ---> c06eaebcfb38
Step 6/8 : RUN npm install &&     npm run start
 ---> Running in e2622118028d
npm WARN lifecycle angular-phonecat@0.0.0~postinstall: cannot run in wd angular-phonecat@0.0.0 npm run copy-libs (wd=/app)
audited 3777 packages in 6.409s
found 57 vulnerabilities (2 low, 2 moderate, 53 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

> angular-phonecat@0.0.0 prestart /app
> npm install

npm WARN lifecycle angular-phonecat@0.0.0~postinstall: cannot run in wd angular-phonecat@0.0.0 npm run copy-libs (wd=/app)
audited 3777 packages in 5.338s
found 57 vulnerabilities (2 low, 2 moderate, 53 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

> angular-phonecat@0.0.0 start /app
> http-server ./app -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1

Starting up http-server, serving ./app
Available on:
  http://localhost:8000
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server
```

But when I open up my browser and navigate to localhost:8000, I get the "this site can't be reached" page. Any idea whats wrong?? Thank you!

**UPDATES**

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:lts-alpine
RUN npm install -g http-server

WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./

COPY . .

RUN npm install 

EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

Docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  front:
    build: .
    ports: 
      - "8000:8000"
```

Terminal

```
Building front
Step 1/8 : FROM node:lts-alpine
 ---> b95baba1cfdb
Step 2/8 : RUN npm install -g http-server
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 082793f64510
Step 3/8 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e76e23fa5a08
Step 4/8 : COPY package*.json ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9960651e0929
Step 5/8 : COPY . .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 35b3086dc43d
Step 6/8 : RUN npm install
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 961eddc4df33
Step 7/8 : EXPOSE 8000
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ede5977a2a0e
Step 8/8 : CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> efc2186c9bf2
Successfully built efc2186c9bf2
Successfully tagged angular-phonecat_front:latest
Chriss-Air:angular-phonecat chrisshopline$ docker-compose up
Creating network "angular-phonecat_default" with the default driver
Creating angular-phonecat_front_1 ... done
Attaching to angular-phonecat_front_1
front_1  | 
front_1  | > angular-phonecat@0.0.0 prestart /app
front_1  | > npm install
front_1  | 
front_1  | npm WARN lifecycle angular-phonecat@0.0.0~postinstall: cannot run in wd angular-phonecat@0.0.0 npm run copy-libs (wd=/app)
front_1  | audited 3777 packages in 4.622s
front_1  | found 57 vulnerabilities (2 low, 2 moderate, 53 high)
front_1  |   run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
front_1  | 
front_1  | > angular-phonecat@0.0.0 start /app
front_1  | > http-server ./app -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1
front_1  | 
front_1  | Starting up http-server, serving ./app
front_1  | Available on:
front_1  |   http://localhost:8000
front_1  | Hit CTRL-C to stop the server
```

Still having the same issue though :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above logs from the Docker build, not from the container. As the build process stuck at

```
RUN npm install && \
    npm run start
```

You do not need to start application at Dockerfile `RUN` command. It should be in `CMD` or `Entrypoint`

Update your Dockerfile and it should work.

```
RUN npm install
```

Also, Something in Docker-compose should be clear.

```
    command: bash -c "npm start"
    volumes: 
      - .:/angular-phonecat
```

- It will override the `CMD` that is defined in Dockerfile CMD `[ "http-server", "dist" ]`.
- It will also override `- .:/angular-phonecat`. you do not need volume if you already copied the app in the build stage.

**update:**

I see that you are setting address in your [package.json](https://github.com/Nigel33/angularJS_docker_test/blob/master/angular-phonecat/package.json) to `localhost`. It should be `0.0.0.0` or you can set `CMD http-server .` or `http-server -a 0.0.0.0 -p 8000 -c-1`. or `http-server -d /app/dist/ -a 0.0.0.0 -p 8000 -c-1.`

Also, the `dist` does not exist in your repo, I assume it exist in your build directory where you copy during docker build.

Comment: Added updates in my original post since comments dont have good formatting. I tried what you suggested and it still seems to have the same problem. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: OMG, thank you SO MUCH! I spent like the whole day on this problem! Could you explain why I need to change to 0.0.0.0 when I'm using docker?

Comment: `localhost` is only accessible inside docker. run command inside docker and check `curl localhost:8000` it should work fine.